# Is there any way to recover recently deleted documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, rollback

I have removed some documents in my last query by mistake, Is there any way to rollback my last query mongo collection.

Here it is my last query :

```
 db.foo.remove({ "name" : "some_x_name"})
```

Is there any rollback/undo option? Can I get my data back?

Comment: Not in this case, it is important to always take a regular backup if you are effecting valuable data; this goes for any database tech

Comment: Backups are always a good idea, but you can also run a replica with a delay to give you an option to correct mistakes in the recent past like this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-a-delayed-replica-set-member/

Comment: You could have done a point in time restore if you used MMS. No other way to rollback!!!!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no rollback option ([rollback has a different meaning](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-rollbacks/) in a MongoDB context), and strictly speaking there is no supported way to get these documents back - the precautions you can/should take are covered in the comments.  With that said however, if you are running a replica set, even a single node replica set, then you have an [`oplog`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#replica-set-oplog).  With an `oplog` that covers when the documents were inserted, you may be able to recover them.

The easiest way to illustrate this is with an example.  I will use a simplified example with just 100 deleted documents that need to be restored.  To go beyond this (huge number of documents, or perhaps you wish to only selectively restore etc.) you will either want to change the code to iterate over a cursor or write this using your language of choice outside the MongoDB shell.  The basic logic remains the same.

First, let's create our example collection `foo` in the database `dropTest`.  We will insert 100 documents without a `name` field and 100 documents with an identical `name` field so that they can be mistakenly removed later:

```
use dropTest;
for(i=0; i < 100; i++){db.foo.insert({_id : i})};
for(i=100; i < 200; i++){db.foo.insert({_id : i, name : "some_x_name"})};
```

Now, let's simulate the accidental removal of our 100 `name` documents:

```
> db.foo.remove({ "name" : "some_x_name"})
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 100 })
```

Because we are running in a replica set, we still have a record of these documents in the `oplog` (being inserted) and thankfully those inserts have not (yet) fallen off the end of the `oplog` (the `oplog` is a [capped collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/) remember) .  Let's see if we can find them:

```
use local;
db.oplog.rs.find({op : "i", ns : "dropTest.foo", "o.name" : "some_x_name"}).count();
100
```

The count looks correct, we seem to have our documents still.  I know from experience that the only piece of the `oplog` entry we will need here is the `o` field, so let's add a projection to only return that (output snipped for brevity, but you get the idea):

```
db.oplog.rs.find({op : "i", ns : "dropTest.foo", "o.name" : "some_x_name"}, {"o" : 1});
{ "o" : { "_id" : 100, "name" : "some_x_name" } }
{ "o" : { "_id" : 101, "name" : "some_x_name" } }
{ "o" : { "_id" : 102, "name" : "some_x_name" } }
{ "o" : { "_id" : 103, "name" : "some_x_name" } }
{ "o" : { "_id" : 104, "name" : "some_x_name" } }
```

To re-insert those documents, we can just store them in an array, then iterate over the array and insert the relevant pieces.  First, let's create our array:

```
var deletedDocs = db.oplog.rs.find({op : "i", ns : "dropTest.foo", "o.name" : "some_x_name"}, {"o" : 1}).toArray();
> deletedDocs.length
100
```

Next we remind ourselves that we only have 100 docs in the collection now, then loop over the 100 inserts, and finally revalidate our counts:

```
use dropTest;
db.foo.count();
100
// simple for loop to re-insert the relevant elements
for (var i = 0; i < deletedDocs.length; i++) {
    db.foo.insert({_id : deletedDocs[i].o._id, name : deletedDocs[i].o.name});
}
// check total and name counts again
db.foo.count();
200
db.foo.count({name : "some_x_name"})
100
```

And there you have it, with some caveats:

- This is not meant to be a true restoration strategy, look at backups (MMS, other), delayed secondaries for that, as mentioned in the comments
- It's not going to be particularly quick to query the documents out of the oplog (any oplog query is a table scan) on a large busy system.
- The documents may age out of the oplog at any time (you can, of course, make a copy of the oplog for later use to give you more time)
- Depending on your workload you might have to de-dupe the results before re-inserting them
- Larger sets of documents will be too large for an array as demonstrated, so you will need to iterate over a cursor instead
- The format of the `oplog` is considered internal and may change at any time (without notice), so use at your own risk

Comment: "There is no rollback option" does this still hold true?

I was going through the documents it seems that when transaction aborts mongo aborts all data changes made, so half baked changes never become available

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Comment: I'm sure this has changed massively in the 7ish years since I answered the question, but I'm afraid I am not current on MongoDB anymore and have not used it for ~6 years. If you have a question about current functionality it's probably best to ask it on DBA Stackexchange

Comment: Just successfully used this approach on 4.4.1.12. Other than the .insert deprecation warning, worked perfectly!

Comment: wow @Half_Duplex - I am genuinely shocked that it still works, thanks for the update :)

Comment: To avoid the warning mentioned by @Half_Duplex and increase performance, instead inserting one by one with a loop, I used this: `db.foo.insertMany(deletedDocs.map(d => d.o), { ordered: false })`

Answer (score 13):

While I understand this is a bit old but I wanted to share something that I researched in this area that may be useful to others with a similar problem.

The fact is that MongoDB does not Physically delete data immediately - it only marks it for deletion. This is however version specific and there is currently no documentation or standardization - which could enable a third party tool developer (or someone in desperate need) to build a tool or write a simple script reliably that works across versions. I opened a ticket for this - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-5151.

I did explore one option which is at a much lower level and may need fine tuning based on the version of MongoDB used. Understandably too low level for most people's linking, however it works and can be handy when all else fails.

My approach involves directly working with the binary in the file and using a Python script (or commands) to identify, read and unpack (BSON) the deleted data.

My approach is inspired by [this](https://gist.github.com/egguy/2788955) GitHub project (I am NOT the developer of this project). [Here on my blog](https://yazadk.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/a-forensic-perspective-on-recovering-deleted-data-from-big-data-systems/#MongoDB) I have tried to simplify the script and extract a specific deleted record from a Raw MongoDB file.

Currently a record is marked for deletion as "`\xee`" at the start of the record. This is what a deleted record looks like in the raw db file,

```
‘\xee\xee\xee\xee\x07_id\x00U\x19\xa6g\x9f\xdf\x19\xc1\xads\xdb\xa8\x02name\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00AAA\x00\x01marks\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x9f@\x00′
```

I replaced the first block with the size of the record which I identified earlier based on other records.

```
y=”3\x00\x00\x00″+x[20804:20800+51]
```

Finally using the BSON package (that comes with pymongo), I decoded the binary to a Readable object.

```
bson.decode_all(y)

[{u’_id': ObjectId(‘5519a6679fdf19c1ad73dba8′), u’name': u’AAA’, u’marks': 2000.0}]
```

This BSON is a python object now and can be dumped into a recover collection or simply logged somewhere.

Needless to say this or any other recovery technique should be ideally done in a staging area on a backup copy of the database file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems rare information.
Would be really helpful!!.

Comment: Welcome - I was a part of a paper I was writing where I also explored how I would do something similar with variable degrees of success with Apache Cassandra and Apache HBase.

Comment: I had a very large data dump to recover, and the fist linked above doesn't handle deleted records on Mongo 2.4 properly like @YazadKhambata have done. So I rewrote the script in the gist with Yazad's information and got this: https://gist.github.com/guss77/f8e610cfddbe02c07896 . I used this to recover many thousands of records from a large deleted collection.

Comment: Is there any way to recover collection remove({}) in 2019?