# How to undo a remove in mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

If I was to accidentally run a `UserModel.remove({}, cb)` and delete all of my user documents, how would I retrieve those documents? Would the process be same on a local DB on my computer VS a DB hosted on a remote server such as mLab?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802786/is-there-any-way-to-recover-recently-deleted-documents-in-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they can not be retrieved back once deleted. The only way to recover the data is to create a dump of that collections before deleting it or if you have a replica of that server. You can restore it from that.