# How to retrieve data in mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question: I tried to delete some records from a MongoDB database. But I want to retrieve data from the MongoDB database. Is it any query or give some suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to recover deleted record?

Comment: yes I want to recover data

Comment: Then possible your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802786/is-there-any-way-to-recover-recently-deleted-documents-in-mongodb